# Make manytomany field hyperlink

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

*I need to change categories in API;
my category and books models are manytomany.*

Code:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','isbn','title','content','price','authors','categories','price_after_discount')
```

Output:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "isbn": "978-1-4061-9242-1",
    "title": "Energy carry different lot. Back room practice with.",
    "content": "Suddenly various answer author.",
    "price": "7346.00",
    "authors": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "categories": [
        2
    ]
},
```

But I need:

```
    "categories": [
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/2/"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the dictionary to fit your needs. I'm not sure if there will be multiple categories, or how you want to deal with multiple of them, but the concept still stands.

```
manytomany = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/"
for category in outputDict["categories"]:
    manytomany += str(category) + "/"

outputDict["categories"] = manytomany
```

Answer (score -1):

you can modify the serializer to use a "HyperlinkedRelatedField" instead of the default "PrimaryKeyRelatedField". this will generate output with urls to the related category objects

so the BookSerializer should be like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    categories = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    many=True,
    read_only=True,
    view_name='category-detail'  # instead of 'category-detail' use the actual name of your category detail view in your URLs.
)
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id','isbn','title','content','price','authors','categories','price_after_discount')
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I understand that this is the usual way of doing this, but unfortunately for me it is an error
 Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "category-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
Another suggestion solved the problem

Comment: I'm glad that the problem is solved :) 

wish you the best.